# Why have my user accounts not been merged?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

I have requested merging my accounts twice. My first donation to Stack Overflow was without an active user. I have since connected with my Facebook ID, but lost the credit. I have then, as I said, followed protocol and asked for my accounts to be merged. Twice. I was ignored.

I would now like to either have my accounts merged right away or my donation in the form of an answer be removed completely.

Comment: Just to make sure, you used the form in the "contact us" link at the bottom to request a merge? And how long ago was that? They might be slow over the holidays as the comm team is mostly away right now.

Comment: Your accounts have been merged now, but for future reference please use the /help links Manis and Mad suggest - it'll keep requests out of the spam box and help us help you more quickly.

Comment: Mad Scientist, I did fill that form, twice. Weeks apart, if I recall correctly. But yes, @Shog9, they are merged now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your current profile says "merge me". You don't specify who you want merging with. Could you give some links where you have done so? And, exactly how did you request a merge? Try https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge or https://stackoverflow.com/help/other if that doesn't work.

For two accounts to be merged, we require *both* users to specify "I want to me merged with X", where X is a link to the userpage of the other user. If both accounts do not do so, we can't be sure that they're the same (well, we *can* in some cases when the IPs match), and we won't merge.

Note that if you delete your own answers it will be undeleted. If you see the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), content you post here is licensed to the SE network and they are free to control how it is used (as well as other things), though your username must be quoted if someone wants to use your content elsewhere. (Your content is still attributed to you)

Comment: Just to get the terminology right here: Any content you contribute is *"perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange*". A nit-pick though, I know.

Comment: @Bart: Changed "property of" to "licensed to". I'm not fixing anything else, it get's too much lawyerspeaky :P

Comment: The rest if fine with me. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's all jargony and such, but... It's a *really* crucial difference. Like giving your neighbor a key to your house vs. giving them the deed.

Comment: @Shog9: True, but it's also pretty irrelevant here to mention how long  it is licensed for-- I only posted that in response to the "I'll delete my posts" bit, not really necessary to go into too many details. Good analogy, though :)

Comment: Note I have not said I would delete my posts. I requested for them to be deleted if I was not to be credited for them. My accounts have now been merged, which is great. I was not able to change BOTH accounts to specify "I want to be merged with..." as my initial user was a guest, and therefore impossible to re-login to, as was also mentioned in my post. Thanks for the detailed response, though.